# How to change views of Entity reference field programmatically?

Tags: views, forms

In my form I have used **auto complete Entity Reference field**. I have set style for this field to loads from **specific views** instead of content.

I have created a view with **two entity reference output**. `EntityReference_1 and EntityReference_2`

by default entity reference field is loaded by `EntityReference_1` result.

But in some cases *(for example if specific user or role is logged)* I want to alter the form and **force** auto complete Entity Reference field to use `EntityReference_2` result .

Please guide me, How can I do this?

Comment: is it a Drupal7 or a Drupal8 question ? Either way you could alter the form, set EntityReference_2 as #default _value and set #disabled => TRUE according to user properties

Comment: Version is Drupal 7